# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute on Entity Framework Interceptor

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-8.0

Hi i'm trying to store about 7000 objects at once via entity framework 8.0 on postgres

```
var citiesJson = File.ReadAllText("Schemas/delivery-cities.json");
var cities = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<DeliveryCityDTO>>(citiesJson);
var tasks = cities.Select(x => _cityService.Seed(x)).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This is how im preparing my tasks and this what is happening in task:

```
public async Task Seed(DeliveryCityDTO city)
{
    var deliveryService = await _context.DeliveryServices.SingleAsync(x => x.Name == city.DeliveryServiceName);

    DeliveryCity deliveryCity = new()
    {
        CityFiasСode = city.CityFiasСode,
        Name = city.Name,
    };

    _context.DeliveryCities.Add(deliveryCity);

    _context.DeliveryServiceDeliveryCities.Add(new DeliveryServiceDeliveryCity
    {
        RefDeliveryCity = deliveryCity.Id,
        RefDeliveryService = deliveryService.Id
    });

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Also i have AuditableEntityInterceptor that configured to run auditable base entities, neither of this entities are not auditable entity and from time to time i got 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute', this falls on following line:

```
if (context.ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseAuditableEntity>().Count() == 0) return;
```

Please help avoid this problem, i see that postgres table is filling up, but this error is annoying.

Comment: The context is not thread safe. Why do you need to parallelize?

Comment: i want to do it fast

Comment: First do it. Then optimize. No use to be fast when all you do is fail fast.

Comment: Also, it's possible to do this for all cities at once.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your code why the exception is thrown. Nothing obviously changes the lists `cities` and `tasks`. It may be an artifact of using one context instance in multiple threads, because that tends to cause all kinds of unpredictable exceptions. That's the first thing you should change anyway, because a context is not thread-safe.

But there's more. The code is also very inefficient (or *chatty*). You process each city individually with two roundtrips per city. Even when doing it in parallel this is probably not the quickest way.

The best way is to process all cities at once. EF core has made inserts (and updates) far more *chunky* than they used to be (i.e. doing more in one query batch), but, of course, only when there is something to do in chunks.

Taking all this into account, here's an effort to improve your code, based on the code you show:

```cs
public async Task Seed(DeliveryCityDTO[] cities)
{
    var names = cities.Select(c => c.DeliveryServiceName).ToList();

    var deliveryServices = await _context.DeliveryServices
        .Where(ds => names.Contains(ds.Name))
        .Select(ds => new { ds.Name, ds.Id })
        .ToDictionary(ds => ds.Name, ds => ds.Id);

    var deliveryCities = cities
        .Select(x => new DeliveryCity
        {
            CityFiasСode = city.CityFiasСode,
            Name = city.Name,
            DeliveryServiceDeliveryCities = new[]
            {
                new DeliveryServiceDeliveryCity
                {
                    RefDeliveryService = deliveryServices[x.DeliveryServiceName]
                }
            }
        });

    _context.DeliveryCities.AddRange(deliveryCities);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This assumes that `City` has a navigation property `DeliveryServiceDeliveryCities` as part of a many-to-many relationship. If not, you better add it.

I'm pretty confident that this single `SaveChanges` call easily outweighs parallelizing the process.

Comment: One comment: since you have 7000 object, you may have to process them in batches, using a new context per batch. This prevents "context bloating". Try to figure out the optimal batch size.

Comment: An extra addition to this very nice and clean code is to use bulk save instead of savechanges.

Comment: I solved it by withdrawing all this parallel programming idea, i saved all 7000 in ChangeTracker and just saved it, and it `s resolved me all

Comment: Do you mean using your code, but now not as Tasks, or the code above? I ask, because it would be a missed chance if you didn't remove the chattiness.